# Server.route does not conform to the expected type requestcontext [Akka,Scala]

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am trying to play around with this example http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M2/scala/http/directives/coding-directives/decodeRequest.html

```
1 def routesWithCompression = {


2   time() {
3     count() {
4       decodeRequest(Gzip) {

5            entity(as[String]) { content: String =>
6              complete(s"Request content: '$content'")
7          }
8          }

9       }
10      }
11 }
```

I get compile error at line 8 stating

> Expression of type server.route does not conform to requestcontext

Honestly, I can't figure out which requires RequestContext as input and how to convert server.route to type RequestContext.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's an outdated experimental version.  If you're using a more recent version of Akka Streams/HTTP, there is a good chance the old code won't compile or run.  You might want to review the latest Akka-HTTP [encoding/decoding example](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/common/de-coding.html) instead.

Comment: I apologize, the link to documentation is old but I am using the current API's  and it has decodeRequest() and encodeResponse() . I don't think there is fault there. Thanks